# How to properly overload functions in typescript interfaces

Tags: typescript

I have following interface

```
interface foo1 {
    add(num1: number, num2: number): number;
    subtract(num1: number, num2: number): number;
}
```

Now I create an object in shape of *foo1*

```
let myFoo1: foo1;

myFoo1.add(5, 6); // OK
myFoo1.subtract(5, 6); // OK
```

Fine, now I create a new interface which I want it to act as an **extension** to the first one

```
interface foo2 {
    add(num1: number, num2: number, num3: number): number;
}
```

Now I create a new object in shape of *foo2*

```
let myFoo2: foo2;

myFoo2.add(5, 6, 7); // OK
myFoo2.subtract(5, 6); // ERROR
```

Basing *myFoo2* on *foo2* interface makes me to use an "upgraded" version of *add* but now I can't access *subtract* function

Here's what I've come up with

```
let myFoo2: foo1 & foo2;

myFoo2.add(5, 6, 7); // OK
myFoo2.subtract(5, 6); // OK
```

Now I can use both the newer version of *add* and also access *subtract* function

Is it the proper way of doing stuff or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you want it to act as an extension, why doesn't it `extend` it? See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces

Comment: Because it doesn't. Here's an error message it gives if you do so: Interface foo2 incorrectly extends interface foo1. Type (num1: number, num2: number, num3: number) => void is not assignable to type (num1: number, num2: number) => number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend `foo1` by making the third argument optional, which it is - because you can pass two *or* three arguments to a method named `add`. This makes it compatible with the `add` method that is inherited.

```
interface foo1 {
    add(num1: number, num2: number): number;
    subtract(num1: number, num2: number): number;
}

interface foo2 extends foo1 {
    add(num1: number, num2: number, num3?: number): number;
}
```

You can then access all the members of `foo1` and `foo2`.

```
var x: foo2;

x.add(1, 2);
x.add(1, 2, 3);
x.subtract(3, 1);
```

Alternatively, you can cut up the interfaces in a different way so that only the add method you want to make available appears:

```
interface foo {
    subtract(num1: number, num2: number): number;
}

interface foo1 extends foo {
    add(num1: number, num2: number): number;
}

interface foo2 extends foo {
    add(num1: number, num2: number, num3: number): number;
}
```

Now both `foo1` and `foo2` have the same subtract method, but different `add` methods.

```
var x: foo2;

// x.add(1, 2); not allowed now
x.add(1, 2, 3);
x.subtract(3, 1);
```

Comment: Can you please comment on foo1 & foo2 ? Should I use your method instead of mine and if so, why?